# Serialization with sealed classes fails in Kotlin serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I'm having trouble with kotlin-serialization in the following use case:

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class NetworkAnswer {
    @SerialName("answerId")
    abstract val id: Int
}

@Serializable
data class NetworkYesNoAnswer(
    override val id: Int,

    @SerialName("isPositive")
    val isPositive: Boolean
) : NetworkAnswer()
```

When I serialize this:

```kotlin
val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true; explicitNulls = false }
val result: NetworkYesNoAnswer = json.decodeFromString(NetworkYesNoAnswer.serializer(), """
            { 
            "answerId": 1, 
            "isPositive": true 
            }
  """.trimIndent()
)
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Fields [id] are required for type with serial name 'NetworkYesNoAnswer', but they were missing
```

The only way the serialization works is if I use the same name for both the member and "SerialName", like so:

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class NetworkAnswer {
    @SerialName("answerId")
    abstract val answerId: Int
}

@Serializable
data class NetworkYesNoAnswer(
    override val answerId: Int,

    @SerialName("isPositive")
    val isPositive: Boolean
) : NetworkAnswer()
```

This kinda defeats the purpose of "SerialName", is there a way to solve that without using the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a `@SerialName` on a base class has no effect on member declarations overridden by child classes.

Instead, you can declare `@SerialName` on the child class instead. There is no need to change the actual name of the field.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class NetworkYesNoAnswer(
    @SerialName("answerId")
    override val id: Int,

    @SerialName("isPositive")
    val isPositive: Boolean
) : NetworkAnswer()
```

Declaring the `@SerialName` on the base class and applying it to all children seems NOT to be supported as of now, but is desired by other members of the community as well, e.g. [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1950#issuecomment-1362986792).

---

OT: Most likely you could use a `sealed interface`, which was first introduced in Kotlin v1.5.0, instead of a `sealed class`.

Comment: So If I have multiple subclasses of NetworkAnswer, there is no other alternative but to define @SerialName("answerId") on each of them?

Comment: @TwoHorses None that I'm aware of, sadly. It makes sense, that you can define a custom serial name on each subclass. However, I personally think that a serial name declared on the base class should be taken into consideration as well, which unfortunately is not the case at this moment.